# Annotation title cannot be shown after change the pincolor

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I used this code to change the annotation's color,but after that,the title and subtitle can not be showed,how can I save this problem?

The code are:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{   
  static NSString *defaultPinID = @"LYB"; 
    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinview = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID]; 
    if ( customPinview == nil ) {
        customPinview = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                    initWithAnnotation:from reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease]; 
    }
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"the first"]) {
        customPinview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }
    return customPinview;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following Code in a new line before "return customPinview":

```
customPinview.canShowCallout = YES;
```